# Are there some program like COM0COM in linux?

Tags: linux, serial-port, com0com

I use com0com for program testing in windows,
are there any program like com0com in linux?

I know there is pts/ptmx, but what I want is a stand alone program to provide 2 virtual serial ports...

Then I can open 2 program, each attench one...

Comment: Don't you mean com0com instead of com2com?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found a good method:

```
socat PTY,link=COM8 PTY,link=COM9
```

then 2 virtual serial port files are created: COM8, COM9

Answer (score 0):

You can also use tty2comKm virtual serial port driver for linux provided by serialpundit project.