# Use serial-console as display, but computer keyboard for standard-input

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, serial-port, inittab

I have a 40x7 VFD that functions as a serial terminal. It has a dedicated keypad that provides hex-entry, however, I would like to use a keyboard for the standard input. Basically, I want to be able to use the VFD as a display for a Linux bash prompt, but use the keyboard connected to the computer as the means of input. Instead of connecting a monitor, the serial terminal will be the monitor. I can get the login prompt displayed on the VFD with agetty, but since it only has hex-entry, how can I change where the system is looking for standard input?

Thanks,
Core_Module

Answer (score 3):

I think the best method would be to create a pseudo terminal. In doing so you create a fake terminal device with a `/dev/pts/[n]` name that acts like a real input/output device. A program could connect the console (keyboard) as input and the VFD as output and send and receive that data over the pseudo device. You can then point `agetty` at the `/dev/pts/[0]` device instead of a `/dev/ttyS[n]` device. Some ideas on doing this can be found in many [tutorials](http://rachid.koucha.free.fr/tech_corner/pty_pdip.html) online. From the link:

> A pseudo-terminal is a pair of character mode devices also called pty. One is master and the other is slave and they are connected with a bidirectional channel. Any data written on the slave side is forwarded to the output of the master side. Conversely, any data written on the master side is forwarded to the output of the slave.

I found another StackOverflow question that may also be of assistance. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500420/fake-serial-communication-under-linux). It could be adapted to suit your needs.