# Null modem emulator (com0com) for linux

Tags: linux, macos, serial-port, socat, com0com

I have a project that contains some unitary tests used to test the serial communications using COM ports (in windows). I use com0com to create a virtual pair of bounded ports and execute the tests.

However I don't know how to do that in Linux neither in MACOS. I've read this topic: [Are there some program like COM0COM in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175440/are-there-some-program-like-com0com-in-linux) Where the answer suggests using socat. I've tried that approach but it doesn't work, my application doesn't detect the ports I've just defined in socat.

```
socat PTY,link=/dev/COM98 PTY,link=/dev/COM99
```

My theory is that socat cannot create virtual ports, it can only bind together existing ports.

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

This is what I get after running the previous socat command. If you look closely, you'll see that COM98 and COM99 ports are in /dev/. However if I write to /dev/COM98 and use *tail -f* to follow COM99 I don't get any output from it.

[image]

**EDIT2:**

Well, if I use cat instead of tail I can see the output (why?!)

[image]

'

'

'

**EDIT3:**

**SOLUTION:** Don't name the ports COMxx but ttySxx instead!

Example:

```
socat PTY,link=/dev/ttyS98 PTY,link=/dev/ttyS99
```

Reason why: Some serial-comm libraries may not support other nomenclature, such as RXTX 2.X.X and previous versions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Virtual Serial Port for Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52187/virtual-serial-port-for-linux)

Comment: I've been into that topic also and it didn't solve the issue. :(

Comment: Why did it not solve your issue?

Comment: I've tried everything but without success. I've added a picture to the OP to help showing the issue.

Comment: I recommend that you edit your question to place edit 3 as an answer, rather than addendum to the question itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
socat -d -d pty,raw,echo=0 pty,raw,echo=0
```

works just fine and prints:

```
2014/05/26 13:29:15 socat[27177] N PTY is /dev/pts/32
2014/05/26 13:29:15 socat[27177] N PTY is /dev/pts/33
2014/05/26 13:29:15 socat[27177] N starting data transfer loop with FDs [3,3] and [5,5]
```

I assume that you should be able to write to /dev/pts/32 and read from /dev/pts/33.

Also is /dev/COM9{8,9} a character device you can use?

```
ls -l /dev/COM989
```

should print a mode which starts with c if that is the case.

Comment: I cannot use /dev/COMxx names in linux somehow. But if I choose /dev/ttySxx names it works fine!

Thanks!

Comment: How do I do `socat -d -d pty,raw,echo=0 pty,raw,echo=0` but specify the `/dev/pts/#` that I want to use?

Comment: I would also like to know the same :)